# Azure Mobile App Authentication 403 on Callback

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the current [Azure Mobile Apps SDK](https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0-rc1.js) for `JavaScript` clients and using the following [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/). I've got all of the main providers registered in `Azure` and they all contain their App ID and secret correctly configured. I'm using the boilerplate code from the SDK to call `Azure Mobile Apps` and the provider login (Twitter, Google, MSFT, FB) will pop up a window in my web app and allow logging in to authenticate. The authentication *works*.

The problem is the callback process back to my originating web app. I get a `403 (Forbidden)` error and the following is displayed in the browser window:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Here are some sample callback URLs (obfuscated values for brevity)

https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback?code=AQB123&state=nonce%3D3
https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/twitter/callback?oauth_token=FhGv&oauth_verifier=abc123
https://myservice.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback?state=nonce%3Dc&authuser=0&session_state=4cf501&prompt=none#

The thing is if I take any of the complete URLs above and paste in a new browser window and make the call I get the following Azure message in the browser:

> You have successfully signed in

OK so the login and authentication *works*, but it appears the callback to the application is failing with that `403 forbidden`. Here are the things I've tried:

1. Allowing "*" origins for `CORS` in Azure configuration on the server for my `Azure Mobile Apps` instance
2. Allowing "*" origins for `CORS` in my `ASP.NET Core` web application
3. Set a super nonrestrictive `Content-Security-Policy` in `index.html`

`<meta http-equiv ="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'">`

This process and code aren't new to me. This all used to work in the old `Azure Mobile Services` instance that is now retired in favor of `Azure Mobile Apps` (sans the `content-security-policy` above; I never needed that previously). I don't think it's a `JavaScript` code issue on my end either because the promise isn't even returned from this process when the `WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient` is called.

Does anyone have any idea what is blocking this full process from completing and causing this `403 forbidden` from the provider login window after authenticating successfully?

**UPDATE:** I created a blog post on this to help others and provide a thorough explanation: [Configure Azure Mobile App Authentication Server-Side for Use With JavaScript Clients](http://www.allenconway.net/2016/11/configure-azure-mobile-app.html)

Comment: The only thing I can find (which you have probably seen already) is this on the official documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/#auth

Comment: @MartynC - you know I had been using that exact link but there was one section that wasn't working the other day in the Azure Portal. There are instructions to go into the **Resource explorer** and modify the config to allow redirect URLs. I tried to go there the other day and Azure would never open the page; it just sat blank. ...and I never went back and tried again. Guess what, THAT WORKED!! So I'll give you the bounty if you provide an answer that details the requirements from the section within that link named "How to: Configure your Mobile App Service for External Redirect URLs"

Comment: Sure thing thanks, let me post it now 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this could be related to redirect URLs which you can configure in the portal. Looking at the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library/#auth) for this. Running locally can cause problems because, by default, App Service authentication is only configured to allow access from your Mobile App backend. Use the following steps to change the App Service settings to enable authentication when running the server locally:

1. Log in to the Azure portal
2. Navigate to your Mobile App backend.
3. Select Resource explorer in the DEVELOPMENT TOOLS menu.
4. Click Go to open the resource explorer for your Mobile App backend in a new tab or window.
5. Expand the config > authsettings node for your app.
6. Click the Edit button to enable editing of the resource.
7. Find the allowedExternalRedirectUrls element, which should be null. Add your URLs in an array:

`"allowedExternalRedirectUrls": [ "http://localhost:3000","https://localhost:3000"],`

Replace the URLs in the array with the URLs of your service, which in this example is http://localhost:3000 for the local service. You could also use http://localhost:4400, depending on how your app is configured.

8. At the top of the page, click Read/Write, then click PUT to save your updates.

You also need to add the same loopback URLs to the CORS whitelist settings:

1. Navigate back to the Azure portal.
2. Navigate to your Mobile App backend.
3. Click CORS in the API menu.
4. Enter each URL in the empty Allowed Origins text box. A new text box is created.
5. Click SAVE

After the backend updates, you will be able to use the new loopback URLs in your app.

Comment: You saved my bacon here man. Many thanks for sharing your knowledge!